# Calculate $\textbf{1}^\mathsf{T}ARA\textbf{1}$, if $R$ has row and column sums $1$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $n\times n$ diagonal matrix $A=[a_i]$. Denote column vector of ones by $\textbf{1}$.

> Calculate $\textbf{1}^\mathsf{T}ARA\textbf{1}$, if $R$ has row and
> column sums $1$.

---

My attempt: Denote elements of $R$ by $r_{ij}$, then
\begin{align}
\textbf{1}^\mathsf{T}ARA\textbf{1}&=\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2r_{ii}+2\sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n\\i\neq j}a_ia_jr_{ij} \\
&\\
\end{align}

I am having difficulty to use the fact that $R$ has column and row sums equal to $1$, so that the expression can be further simplified. $R$ here is [a relative gain array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_Gain_Array#:%7E:text=The%20Relative%20Gain%20Array%20RGA,for%20multivariable%20process%20control%20systems.) matrix, so it has additional nice math properties.